# How can I annotate my method to return a Visibility type int in Android?

Tags: android

Android studio complains when I return a regular int and try to use that int as an input parameter to a Visibility-annotated int. How can I annotate my method so that AS doesn't produce this warning? I see that View has a public @interface "Visibility" but for some weird reason I can't reference `android.view.View.Visibility` from my project even if it's public. Why?

My method:

```
public static int booleanToVisibleOrInvisible(boolean visible) {
    return visible ? View.VISIBLE :  View.INVISIBLE;
}
```

What I need:

```
@android.view.View.Visibility  // <- does not compile
public static int booleanToVisibleOrInvisible(boolean visible) {
    return visible ? View.VISIBLE :  View.INVISIBLE;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> but for some weird reason I can't reference android.view.View.Visibility from my project even if it's public.

Take a look into the source code, you'll see that this annotation is 'annotated' with the `@hide` tag:

```
/** @hide */
@IntDef({VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, GONE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Visibility {}
```

`@hide` tag is used to exclude the annotated package/class/method/etc from the `android.jar` file so it's not available at compile time. I doubt you can somehow use this same annotation in your code unless Google engineers remove the `@hide` tag from the sources.
You can suppress this warning with `//noinspection ResourceType` comment.

Comment: Wow... Blurring the line between code and comments there Google. Thanks for the heads up. PS: I had to write `@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")` to make it work. PPS: Ah, the other one works inline.

Comment: why is that annotation even hidden?